# Loading and displaying JPG image by code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to load and display an image using WPF, but it does not work.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BitmapImage imgsrc;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        imgsrc = new BitmapImage();
        imgsrc.BeginInit();
        imgsrc.UriSource = new Uri("c.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        imgsrc.EndInit();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
         base.OnRender(drawingContext);
         drawingContext.DrawImage(imgsrc, new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

the c.jpg file is in the project and marked for copy to output.

the applications runs without errors and shows a white empty window

Comment: Any error message? did you check if imgsrc contains loaded image data?

Comment: nope, no errors, when i check with a breakpoint i get a filenotfound on the imgsrc members

Comment: Where is the img located in your project structure?

Comment: do you copy c.jpg to output directory?

Comment: @KyorCode it is in the root of the project, next to App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml

Comment: There may be scenarios - but why do you want to draw the image manually?

Comment: A reach buy try putting c.jpg in the directory with the exe

Comment: if i manually copy the c.jpg to the bin/Debug directory then i dont get the filenotfoundexception but i still dont see any image but only i white window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/750e91c2-c370-4f0a-b18e-892afd99bd9b) with overriding `OnRender()` on a `Window`.

Don't derive from `Window`, use `FrameworkElement` instead, or if you must use `Window` try setting the background to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The OnRender(...) method on classes inheriting from Window does not work how you excpect. 
You might try something like this:

In your XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:own="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <own:MyRect />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And here your element that displays your image (replace the rectangle with your image logic)

```
public class MyRect : Panel
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.LimeGreen;
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 10);
        Rect myRect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(mySolidColorBrush, myPen, myRect);
    }
}
```